# Lumia + MS Exchange - cannot acess phone content by USB cable

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, lumia-520, windows-8, exchange, windows-7

We have a couple of Windows Phone 8 Lumia phones. They are configured for synchronization with MS Exchange server account ( mail, address book, calendar, contacts). Whole communication use ssl. Security profile require remote data wiping and pin settings as mandatory.

When phone is not configured with Exchange account or is factory reset - we can access content by usb cable - and copy photos for example.
When configuration of Exchange is in place ( account is defined etc.) - there is no possibility to access photos and any other content from the phone by usb cable nor bluetooth.

There is no problem with android phones. 
Problem occurs only on Lumia after upgrade to 8 version of windows.

Do You have any idea why?

Comment: Have you checked with your Exchange administrator to find out if they enforce any other policeis?

Comment: I am the Exchange Administrator and there is no more policies that pin security